# Run-time error '-2147217900 (80040e14) while trying to retrieving data from SQL Server using VBA

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I am trying to connect to SQL Server from Excel VBA using the following code. But when I run the below query, I get an error

> Run-time error '-2147217900 (80040e14).

Here is my code:

```
    Dim objMyConn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim objMyCmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim objMyCmd1 As ADODB.Command
    Dim objMyRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim rngUsedRange

    Set objMyConn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set objMyCmd = New ADODB.Command

    Set objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
    Set rngUsedRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

'Open Connection'

    objMyConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=10.5.3.16;Initial Catalog=PROTELECOM_AMERICAN_TOWERS;Trusted_connection=yes;"
    objMyConn.Open

'Set and Excecute SQL Command'
    Set objMyCmd.ActiveConnection = objMyConn
objMyCmd.CommandText = ";WITH CTE AS(SELECT BAN.BAN_IDFR, BAN.BAN_NBR, BAN.BAN_STATUS FROM PROTELE_BAN BAN INNER JOIN PROTELE_BILL BILL ON BAN.BAN_IDFR = BILL.BAN_IDFR" & _
"GROUP BY BAN.BAN_IDFR,BAN.BAN_NBR,BAN.BAN_STATUS)SELECT DISTINCT V.ORG_NAME [VENDOR NAME], CTE.BAN_NBR [BAN#], SVR.SER_ACCT_NBR [WTN#],W.COST_CENTER[COST CENTER],W.COST_CODE[COST CODE], BA.ECOM_ID [VENDOR ID],BC.SERVICE_TYPE [SERVICE TYPE], CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),MAX(B.BILL_DATE),101) AS [BILL DATE],SUM(BC.AMOUNT) AMOUNT, B.EXTRACT_STATUS [EXTRACT STATUS],CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),B.EXTRACT_DATE,101) AS [EXTRACTED DATE]" & _
"FROM CTE INNER JOIN PROTELE_BILL B ON CTE.BAN_IDFR = B.BAN_IDFR" & _
"INNER JOIN PROTELE_BILL_CHARGE BC ON B.BILL_IDFR = BC.BILL_IDFR" & _
"INNER JOIN PROTELE_BAN_WTN_MAPPING MAPP ON B.BAN_IDFR = MAPP.BAN_IDFR" & _
"INNER JOIN PROTELE_SVR_WTN SVR ON SVR.SVR_ACCT_IDFR=BC.SVR_ACCT_IDFR" & _
"INNER JOIN PROTELE_SVR_WTN_DETAILS W ON CTE.BAN_IDFR = W.BAN_IDFR AND SVR.SVR_ACCT_IDFR = W.SVR_ACCT_IDFR AND B.BAN_IDFR=W.BAN_IDFR" & _
"INNER JOIN PROTELE_BAN_VENDOR BV ON CTE.BAN_IDFR = BV.BAN_IDFR" & _
"INNER JOIN PROTELE_BAN BA ON CTE.BAN_IDFR = BA.BAN_IDFR" & _
"INNER JOIN PROTELE_LOCATION C ON C.LOCA_IDFR = BV.VNDR_LOCA_IDFR" & _
"INNER JOIN PROTELE_VENDOR V ON C.ORG_IDFR = V.ORG_IDFR WHERE BC.SVR_ACCT_IDFR=W.SVR_ACCT_IDFR AND (B.EXTRACT_DATE BETWEEN '02/05/2016' AND '02/06/2016')" & _
"GROUP BY CTE.BAN_NBR, B.EXTRACT_DATE, BA.ECOM_ID,B.BILL_DATE,B.EXTRACT_STATUS,BC.SERVICE_TYPE,W.COST_CENTER,W.COST_CODE, SVR.SER_ACCT_NBR,V.ORG_NAME" & _
"ORDER BY CTE.BAN_NBR, V.ORG_NAME;"
objMyCmd.CommandType = adCmdText
'Open Recordset'
    Set objMyRecordset.Source = objMyCmd
    objMyRecordset.Open
    For intColIndex = 0 To objMyRecordset.Fields.Count - 1
    Selection.Offset(0, intColIndex).Value = objMyRecordset.Fields(intColIndex).Name
    Next

'Copy Data to Excel'
    ActiveSheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset objMyRecordset
```

Comment: What line causes the error?

Answer (score 3):

The one thing that jumps to my attention is your concatenations.  You don't seem to be padding spaces or return characters between your concats.

For example, when you do this:

```
sql = "select one, two, three" & _
      "from x"
```

it will render the output as:

```
select one, two, threefrom x
```

Which should error.

Can you add spaces at the end of each string and see if that helps?  With the exception of that, I don't see any glaring issues with the code.